# Configure the automatic password while taking the Database backup from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I received one requirement from client,if any take the database backup from SQL Server, backup will by default contains the password.

so No One can restore the database without password.

I suggests the TDE encryption solution but he is not agree with this.

anyone one know, Is there any SQL setting for this?

Thanks
Nirav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDK if there is any built-in option (*except TDE*). We are using WinRAR for similar purpose :

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
DECLARE @fileName varchar(1000)
DECLARE @pathName varchar(1000)
DECLARE @backupName varchar(1000)
DECLARE @backupFullName varchar(1000)
DECLARE @rarName varchar(1000)
DECLARE @compressCommand varchar(1000)
DECLARE @deleteBakCommand varchar(1000)
DECLARE @deleteRarCommand varchar(1000)
DECLARE @moveCommand varchar(1000)
DECLARE @deleteOldRarCommand varchar(1000)

SET @fileName = 'database' + CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(weekday,getdate()))
set @pathName = 'D:\folder\'
SET @backupName = @fileName + '.bak'
SET @rarName = @fileName + '.rar'
SET @backupFullName =@pathName + @backupName
SET @compressCommand = 'C:\Progra~1\WinRAR\rar a -m5 -pPASSWORD '+ @pathName + @rarName + ' ' + @pathName+@backupName + '"'
SET @deleteBakCommand = 'del ' +   @pathName + @backupName 
SET @deleteRarCommand = 'del ' +   @pathName + @rarName
SET @deleteOldRarCommand = 'del ' +   @pathName + 'TARGET\db\' +  @rarName
set @moveCommand = 'copy /y ' + @pathName+@rarName + ' ' + @pathName + 'TARGET\db\' + @rarName

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @deleteBakCommand;
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @deleteRarCommand;
BACKUP DATABASE DBNAME TO DISK = @backupFullName;

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @deleteOldRarCommand;
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @compressCommand;
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @deleteBakCommand;
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @moveCommand;
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @deleteRarCommand;

GO
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 0
```

Comment: But what happen, if someone take the backup from SSMS using GUI like SQL Administrator

Comment: I know it is not elegant solution in first place. And; there is `backupoperator` privilege, you can restrict users against to gui backups.